# How to do multiple save object calls in a Django view, but commit only once

Tags: django, model, save, commit

I have a Django view in which I call `my_model.save()` in a single object (conditionally) in *multiple* spots. `my_model` is a normal model class.

`save()` is commited at once in Django, and thus, the database gets hit several times in the worst case. To prevent this, I defined a boolean variable `save_model` and set it to `True` in the case of a object modification. At the end of my view, I check this boolean and call `save` on my object in needed.

Is there a simpler way of doing this? I tried Djangos `transaction.commit_on_success` as a view decorator, but the save-calls appear to get queued and committed anyway.

Comment: You've misunderstood how transactions work. Inside a transaction, all operations are still sent to the database - it's just that the database isolates those operations until the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into [django-dirtyfields](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/django-dirtyfields/).

Simply use `DirtyFieldsMixin` as a mixin to your model. You will then be able to check if an object has changed (using `obj.is_dirty()`) before doing a `save()`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. Quite useful... Anyways, in my simple case, I stick with the boolean, since DirtyFieldsMixin is a bit overkill for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use transaction support everywhere in your code, Django docs say it explicitely:

> Although the examples below use view functions as examples, these decorators and context managers can be used anywhere in your code that you need to deal with transactions

But this isn't the thing transactions are for. You can get rid of your boolean variable using some existing app for that, like [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/smn/django-dirtyfields).

But it smells like a bad design. Why do you need to call `save` multiple times? Are you sure there is no way to call it only once?

Comment: I used commit_on_success on the whole view and the database commits are postponed until the successful end of the view, but still one gets multiple calls to the database in sequence.
Anyways, in most cases, the object doesn't get saved at all, that why I use the boolean.

Comment: @Nasmon If in most cases, the object doesn't get saved at all, why do you call its `save` all the time?

Comment: The model only gets saved, when my bool variable is true.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approaches for this... But they are similar... First one is calling `save()` before returning response.

```
def my_view(request):
    obj = Mymodel.objects.get(...)
    if cond1:
        obj.attr1 = True
    elif cond2:
        obj.attr2 = True
    else:
        obj.attr1 = False
        obj.attr2 = False
    obj.save()
    return .......
```

Second one is your approach...

But there is no other way to do this, except you define your own decorator or do some other approach, but in fact, you need to check if there is any modification on your model (or you want to save changes to your data).